# How to speed up android ndk builds

Tags: android, c++, performance, build, android-ndk

We have a quite large C++ project that we build cross platform for Android and iOS. Xcode uses all cores when compiling and is much faster (4-5x depending on machine). Is there any way to improve the abysmal performance of the NDK? Any multi CPU options? We have precompiled headers, but it seems to me it is use of resources that is at fault.

So any tips or tricks to speed up android ndk project build times would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You aren't required to use Android's build system for your compilation; the tools are all available for use within a Makefile (though you will need to take care to set up include paths, library paths, and compiler options).

Since you can create your own Makefile instead of using the default build scripts, you can use th `-jN` option to specify the number of simultaneous operations to perform.

Comment: The `ndk-build` command itself is using make. You could just use `ndk-build -jN`.

Comment: @usman the N is not literal, you need to place a number there, chosen based on the number of CPU cores on your build system. Example: -j4

Comment: @kennyTM  i did j2. Same command builds things much faster on my friend's system

Comment: Great! Especially the `ndk-build` option from @KennyTM. You can also specify the -jN option in eclipse in `project properties` and then `C/C++ Build` and then override the default build command to add the `-jN` switch.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. You just made may day :-) I am ndk-build ing with -j8 on my mac in almost no time.

Comment: How can I do it using Android Studio with NDK?

Answer (score 4):

Following fragment of bulid.gradle shows an example of **-jN** and **abifilters** : (see http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html and https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkOptions.html)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "test"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21

    ndk {
        moduleName "native_lib"
        abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments '-j4'
        }
    }
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}.....
```

Comment: This fails `Could not find method arguments() for arguments [-j4] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkBuildOptions`

Answer (score 3):

For everyone receiving the following error

> Could not find method arguments() for arguments [-jx] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkBuildOptions.

There is a difference between

`android.externalNativeBuild` [(here)](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.NdkBuildOptions.html) and

`android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild` [(here)](http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeNdkBuildOptions:arguments).

`android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild` accepts `arguments` and can be used to set `-j` option.